# Which city has been captured most frequently?

Tags: war, conquest

According to Wiki, [Jerusalem has been captured and re-captured 44 times in History](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jerusalem/UEMBYHTE?ref=EKISRSTL).

I found this number to be quite high (as one would expect with Jerusalem) and it got me wondering if any other cities have changed hands more times than that?

**Which city would hold the title of most captured city in history?**

*NB: By capture, this could be any duration, even if the victor only held it for a day before loosing it again. As long as the captor was effectively in control of it for any period of time I would count it.*

Comment: Does it still count as "captured" if the city surrenders without a fight?

Comment: @Semaphore I would say yes!

Comment: Guys, if your answer is "some random canditates which _might_ be the answer", then **it is not an answer**. Might be useful, but still it's not an answer. Post it in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Civ fans have some candidates: http://apolyton.net/showthread.php/168921-Most-captured-city

Comment: Does captured include cities which changed hands based on territorial conquests or regime changes without having actual troops march through them?

Comment: I don't have a specific candidate in mind, but I have read that a town in the Shenandoah Valley, probably Front Royal, Virginia, changed hands dozens of times during the US Civil War from 1861-1865.   If a town can come so close to Xi'an's record in just 4 years, it is possible that some ancient city in Asia, Africa, or Europe beats it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### The City of [Xi'an / Hsi-an](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi%27an) aka [Ch'ang-an](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27an) aka [Hao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haojing) - 51 (58) times

1. 771 B.C. - conquered by the [Quanrong barbarians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanrong)
2. 771 B.C. - recovered by [Qin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state)) forces
3. 207 B.C. - captured by [Liu Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Gaozu_of_Han)'s army
4. A.D. 23 - captured  by the [Green Forests Army](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BClin) rebels
5. 25 - captured by the [Red Eyebrows Army](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Eyebrows) rebels
6. 26 - recovered by [Deng Yu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deng_Yu)
7. 192 - captured by [Li Jue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Jue_(Han_dynasty)) and [Guo Si](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guo_Si)
8. 198 - captured by Duan Wei
9. 306 - sacked by forces under [Sima Yue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sima_Yue)
10. 307 - recovered by sacked by forces under [Sima Yue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sima_Yue)
11. 311 - captured by [Han Zhao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Zhao) forces
12. 312 - recovered by Jin loyalist forces
13. 313 - partially captured by Han Zhao's [Liu Yao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Yao) in surprise attack
14. 313 - abandoned to Jin relief forces
15. 316 - conquered by Liu Yao
16. 329 - capitulated to [Shi Le](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi_Le) after being abandoned by the royal court
17. 332 - captured by Shi Le's nephew [Shi Hu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi_Hu)
18. 350 - conquered by [Fu Jian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu_Jian_%28317%E2%80%93355%29)
19. 385 - conquered by [Western Yan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Yan)
20. 386 - captured by [Yao Chang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao_Chang)
21. 417 - recovered by the Eastern Jin
22. 418 - conquered by [Helian Bobo's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helian_Bobo) forces
23. 426 - captured by [Northern Wei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Wei)
24. 428 - abandoned to advancing [Xia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xia_%28Sixteen_Kingdoms%29) forces
25. 430 - recovered by Northern Wei
26. 467 - recovered by Northern Wei after an royal prince revolted in the city
27. 532 - captured by Northern Wei rebels
28. 614 - captured by the rebelling [Li Yuan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Gaozu_of_Tang)
29. 756 - fell to rebels during the [An Lushan Rebellion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Lushan_Rebellion)
30. 757 - recovered by Tang government forces
31. 763 - captured by the [Tibetan Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Empire)
32. 763 - abandoned to Tang reinforcements 15 days later
33. 783 - fell to rebels headed by [Zhu Ci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhu_Ci)
34. 784 - recovered by Tang government forces
35. 881 - fell to [Huang Chao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huang_Chao) insurrection
36. 882 - recovered by Tang government forces
37. 882 - recaptured by Huang Chao the next night
38. 883 - recovered by Tang government forces
39. 895 - seized by [Li Maozhen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huang_Chao)
40. 909 - seized by [Liu Zhijun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Zhijun_(Later_Liang))
41. 909 - recovered by [Zhu Wen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhu_Wen)
42. 934 - capitulated to [Later Tang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Later_Tang) rebels
43. 948 - seized by rebels
44. 949 - recovered by [Later Han](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Later_Han_(Five_Dynasties)) forces
45. 1128 - conquered by [Jin forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(1115%E2%80%931234))
46. 1230 - conquered by the Mongols
47. 1369 - captured by [Ming forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_dynasty)
48. 1643 - captured by rebels under [Li Zicheng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Zicheng)
49. 1645 - conquered by [Manchurian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_dynasty) forces
50. 1911 - captured by Republican revolutionaries
51. 1949 - captured by Communist Chinese forces

The following involve hostile forces taking control of the city, but mostly from within (as coups, revolts, etc), so not sure if we want to count them:

1. 467 - seized in revolt by a Northern Wei prince
2. 626 - seized in coup by [Crown Prince Li Shimin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Taizong_of_Tang)
3. 705 - seized in coup by [Imperial Chancellor Zhang Jianzhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhang_Jianzhi)
4. 710 - seized in coup by [Prince Li Longji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Xuanzong_of_Tang)
5. 835 - seized in coup by [eunuchs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweet_Dew_Incident)
6. 904 - seized in coup by [Zhu Wen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhu_Wen)
7. 1936 - seized in [pro-Communist/Chinese Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi'an_Incident) coup

Answer (score 1):

The city of Xuzhou in China is said to have seen 200 notable battles. I don't know how many of these ended with the city being captured, but it seems like it would rank very high.

I did a quick check and between 1911 and 1948 it changed hands at least 5 times.

Comment: I was thinking somewhere in China myself. Xi'an (西安) was the one I was looking at. When the city was known as Chang'an (长安), it was repeatedly sacked during the [An Lushan Rebellion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Lushan_Rebellion) alone. I think most strategically important cities in China would give Jerusalem a serious run for its money.

Comment: @Comintern That was actually my first thought, too. I tried to compile a list over the last couple of nights, but unfortunately came out at ~41 or so. After ~A.D. 1000, Its remoteness from the coast/southeast really hampered from this dubious "honour", it seems.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, Jerusalem has been controlled by the most separate governments. What I mean is that once it has been controlled by one government, if that government reconquers, then you do not add another number. In this case, Jerusalem, I believe, has been captured the most times.

Comment: Could you expand your answer? How many is "the most times"? Do you have perhaps the beginning of a list of capturers?

Answer (score -3):

Some cities have been around for a very long time. Alexandria (in Egypt) and Damascus (in Syria) would certainly come out very high on your list.

Comment: Jerusalem? I hear it's been bloody there.

Comment: True for Damascus, it's one of the oldest cities in the world. Alexandria though was established by Alexander, way after Jerusalem and Damascus. And without being rude, this doesn't really provide an answer :)

Comment: Yes, but Egypt did change hands a large number of times since the foundation of Alexandria (Ptolemies, Romans, Sasanians, Romans (Byzantines) again, numerous rival Muslim dynasties, Mamluks, Ottomans, Albanians, British....)

Comment: True you have a point

Answer (score -4):

Cities or municipalities in ancient Mesopotamia can be the clear candidate. Sumerians, Babylonians, Assyrians, Alexander, Romans, a long list. Considering how old the city is can have a certain assurance on how many times the city has been turned over.

Comment: This seems like a logical argument without proof. Logically one could think there would be very old cities which have low strategic value that wouldn't really have a high amount if turnover. You need evidence to back up your claims.